# aws lambda domain whitelist

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, aws-lambda, whitelist

I am hoping to restrict an aws lambda to a specific domain (maybe whitelist local dev too) with a specific domain so that others can't use the lambda if they reach it from a domain that isn't in a whitelist.

Is this possible as a service?

Comment: How are you currently triggering lambda function ? You can integrate it with API gateway and check for origin or Referer before trigger it.

Comment: @JamesDean I can integrate it, I'm guessing I check the origins in the gateway config?

Comment: You can use waf with api gateway and you can deny requests without your origin/referer domain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]AWS Lambda will not work alone itself you need to integrate with API Gateway or any other services.
As per your requirement, you need to integrate your Lambda with API Gateway.
Now follow the step:

- Go to API Gateway
- Select your API
- Click Action->Enable Cors
- Fill your domain inside Access-Control-Allow-Origin field. e.g; dev.yourdomain.com
  [Screenshot][2]